# Background image of a li under the background image of the ul

Tags: css, background

How can you do this in css?
I want the background image of the li's to slide under the background image of the ul where they are in.
I tried to do it with z-index but it didn't work.

```
li{
list-style:none;
background-image:url("2.png");
z-index:-10;
position:relative;
}
ul{
    background-image:url("1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
```

Is this possible? And how is it done if it is.

update: Picture explaining what i mean
[image: css menu picture]

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.  You can't control just background images in relation to other backgrounds in other elements, you have to move the entire element behind another.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you could maybe think of looking at CSS3 multiple backgrounds.  That will let you layer background images on the same element.

Comment: If you could provide an image on how it should look, we could give you a definite answer. There might be some techniques with :before/:after that might work etc..

Comment: I added the picture in the post

Comment: I can do it, wait I will make a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I like the idea so much I just made it for you jarco.</strike> It seems it is not as exact as you want but, it is pretty similar.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/V79Lp/)

---

A little `div` to show the bar, and `script` to bring it up and down

```
$("ul").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#bar").animate({
        height: $("ul").height()
    });
}).mouseleave( function() {
    $("#bar").animate({
        height: 20
    });
});
```

#### [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/V79Lp/1/) with the heights

Comment: I think My image is not clear. They should be background images.
The red one is the background of the ul and the blue the background of the li.

Comment: @jarco, too bad. I made it working with the height too. If you want check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/V79Lp/1/)

Comment: Just so I'm clear, is the problem with Starx's fiddle the fact that the red bar doesn't overlap the `ul` background?

Comment: In my picture the red bar IS the ul background. That ul background should overlap the li background.

Comment: @Jarco... I am sorry, but I am no longer interested on this post. Hope you don't mind